# Search box in my Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I am building an application for Windows Phone 7 where i need to have a search box. On clicking the search box it should display the cityname which are already there in the webservice. I am not getting the idea on how to proceed. Please help

Comment: @har07 Hey can you give me some idea for this

Comment: do you mean AutoCompleteBox?

Comment: @ChrisShao Ya autocompletebox. i have done this. Please see the code i posted in my new question

Comment: Yeah, I have answered your new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is **AutoCompleteBox** in wp toolkit, use it like this:
just bind the datasource to your AutoCompleteBox and set the ItemFilter

XAML:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="peopleBox" Height="70"/>
```

Code:

```
this.peopleBox.ItemsSource = myDataSource;
this.peopleBox.ItemFilter += SearchCountry;
```

The SearchCountry is:

```
bool SearchCountry(string search, object value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                //return true if it contains the search key
                if (value.ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(search) >= 0)
                    return true;
            }
            // if not, return false
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: and what's the matter?

Comment: you can debug it. see what the dataSource is? is it null? and see if the SearchCountry method is excute?